# IntelliJ Idea - Android Virtual Device doesn't start

Tags: android, ubuntu, intellij-idea, android-studio, ubuntu-12.04

I'm using **IntelliJ Idea 13** to develop Android applications on **Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit**. But my virtual device never starts despite there is no error.. its screen always stays like this:[image: screenshot-screen]

My Android target level is **4.4 (API 19)**. How can I solve this issue?

**Edit: Here is my AVD details:**

[image: screenshot-avd-details]

Comment: Does the AVD start from AVD manager? I have similar issues with api level 14. What happens if you switch to a different API level?

Comment: How long did you leave it?  It might make sense to do your primary development using a real device and save the extremely painful emulator for when you want to test different screen sizes etc.

Comment: @super-qua tested with other APIs, nothing changes.

Comment: @Poldie waited almost more than 10 minutes.

Comment: @talha06 I'd seriously give it 30 mins next time you need a break. Depending on the spec of your PC that might not be enough.  It's one reason to use a VM to do Android dev if you're using an emulator; once the emulator is running you never kill it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My AVD has started after I check `"Use Host GPU"` option from `"Emulation Options"`.

Answer (score 1):

I Recommend you look at this post to a similar question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5535532/2978914
they are using eclipse but you should be able to view the logcat, other posts say first load can be ridiculously long.
the spec of your PC may come into play as this post https://superuser.com/a/347298 explains the way the emulator converts to arm opcode: direct quote:

> To use emulator more effectively, this is my experience:
>
> - Don't close emulator everytime you run your application.
> - Scale the emulator screen smaller.
> - Disable snapshot (Yes, it's useful but it takes time to close the emulator).
> - Specify a file path for SD card image file. I use only one SD card for many AVDs.
> - If you got any problems in adb, just reset adb, don't close emulator.
> - Open few programs in your operating sytem.
> - If you are using Windows, don't ever close emulator. Do it combined with Hibernate of Windows.