# Eclipse missing action Set

Tags: java, eclipse, adt

I have a problem while opening Eclipse. In the error log it says:

```
unable to find action set org.eclipse.wb.core.ui.actionset 
       org.eclipse.rse.core.search.searchActionSet
       org.eclipse.rse.core.search.searchActionSet
       org.eclipse.mylyn.doc.actionSet
       org.eclipse.mylyn.context.ui.actionSet
```

I'm using Eclipse juno(version 4.2) and my ADT is version20 and Java 1.6
Do you have any idea what I am supposed to do?

Comment: Reinstall? It sounds like something in your base Eclipse installation is bad or missing.

Comment: I've just done it (install the same version) the installation completed with no problems but still the same errors appear.In my research what  i found out was that most likely the problem would be a previous java version but here that's not the problem...

Comment: Other than the error log entries, what else is the problem? Often times there are strange entries in the error logs due to various minor problems with plugins.

Comment: Oh well,look I start working regularly in eclipse developing an app for android,In the first 3-4 hours the virtual device of android takes about 3-5 minutes after another 2-3hours it takes about 10,yesterday it wouldn't open at all by the end of the day.I figured it was because of the log errors.Could it be anything else?

Comment: Yes, I don't know anything about the Android stuff, but I imagine it's specific to that. I don't think it's related to this message. I would search Google for things related to "slowness using Eclipse with Android".

Comment: Consider these links for the slowness issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210198/unbearably-slow-android-emulator-is-there-a-fix

Comment: @FrancisUpton I've used the first og your links i've already seen the second.I've done the snapshot trick and it seems to work fine:) one question though,once i start from snapshot my logcat in eclipse seems as it's not connected with the emulator the only way is to open it from the command promt?or is there another way to start it from the eclipse?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know anything about the Andriod Emulator. You might consider asking a separate question about that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think that this can happen when features are removed from Eclipse and a workspace is not properly updated. Create a new workspace, import all your projects, and delete the old workspace.

Comment: You can use Imports -> General -> Existing Project into Workspace, but be careful that you don't import all your problems again.

Answer (score 29):

In general this is a leftover from something you have uninstalled. To get rid of the error, close Eclipse, find the `workbench.xml` (XML) and `workbench.xmi` (XMI) files in either the

```
.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench\
```

or

```
.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\
```

directories within your workspace and remove ALL corresponding lines (search for the package name you see in the message).

Comment: I removed the directory (workspace)/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench and problem went away. I've tried many things before, this was the only one that worked.

Comment: It's working, but the Eclipse must be stopped until editing both files.

Comment: I just reset my workspace by deleting <workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\workbench.xmi
while eclipse was closed.

Answer (score 1):

I went to the run configurations for the RCP app I had (created using EMF) and I checked the radio box under the Run--> configurations... dialog to "Clear workspace" before running.  This fixed the issue about the missing ActionSets.  I tried to find the references to the missing ActionSets per the above method and that did not fix the bug (there were no references to the missing ActionSets in the workbench.xml or workbench.xmi files.  I am using Kepler SR2 on Mac OS X 10.9.2.

Comment: "Run--> configurations... dialog to "Clear workspace" before running" did not fix the issue about the missing ActionSets BUT my app was able to start again. This saved me my nerves! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem due to a particular view (although I'm not sure what caused it in the first place).  I simply closed the view and restarted Eclipse - problem solved!