# Failed to run the Android SDK Manager

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and Eclipse Juno. I installed the ADT 21.0.1 and all the SDK packages. 
But every time I started the Eclipse there would be errors as following:

```
    eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800
    java.version=1.7.0_09
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
    Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

    Error
    Unable to find Action Set: org.eclipse.mylyn.context.ui.actionSet
    Unable to find Action Set: org.eclipse.mylyn.doc.actionSet
    Unable to find Action Set: org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.navigation
    Unable to find Action Set: org.eclipse.wb.core.ui.actionset
```

And when i tried to run my sdk Manager It show an error:

```
    Failed to run the Android SDK Manager. Check the Android Console View for details.
```

Can anybody helps?

Comment: Did you try the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535784/eclipse-missing-action-set)?

Comment: Sorry for not finishing this question in time. I finally fixed this problem by removing all the files from my workspace and increasingly adding them back. In that way, I found out that the problem is caused by a third-party package which was developed using some kind of version control system which was not supported by my Eclipse. So I removed the file for that vcs from the folder of the package and It was done.    Thank you all the same!

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem when starting the SDK Manager from Eclipse under Mac OS following the update to ADT 21.0.1. I noticed that the <sdk_tools_dir>/tools/android shell program file was no longer eXecutable. A quick

```
chmod a+x android
```

fixed the problem and now the manager launches correctly from within Eclipse. You may have to do this as root. This may be a bug following updates on Unix based distributions, but since I am not using Linux I can't be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and as previously said a chmod on sdk/tools/android helps to recover the SDK Manager window (`chmod a+x android`). Nevertheless, if it still doesn't work for the emulator, perform the same chmod on all the files that begin with "emulator" (same folder)

Answer (score 0):

I know this may sound stupid, but did you move any of the files? I did that once to the executable file thinking it would copy the file and create a shortcut (as it did in previous versions of windows), but instead it actually moved the file location causing it to throw an error (albeit one that was a little different than the one you're getting).

I've also heard that Juno has bugs. You might just want to uninstall Eclipse and all of its file associations an then reinstall an older version.

Comment: I installed the earlier version Indigo(without uninstalling the Juno), and installed the ADT 21.0.1, and still can not run SDK Manager.

Comment: Is it still giving you the same error? And have you moved _any_ files either from the Android SDK or Eclipse at all?