# Eclipse Plugins: Retrieving the missing HelloWorld.actionSet

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno, eclipse-pde

Using Juno and Eclipse PDE. 
Trying to create a simple plug-in (using the template *Hello, World Command)*. When I run it the following message appears in the log:

!MESSAGE Unable to find Action Set: HelloWorld.actionSet

As suggested over at [Q: Eclipse Missing Action Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535784/eclipse-missing-action-set), I created a new workspace, re-created the project and re-installed PDE. None of that has had any effect.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should list what version of Eclipse you are running (Help > About)

Does the hello world action you created show up in the UI?

Have you modified the plug-in in some way?  The hello world with command template does not contribute an action set, only command/handler/binding/menu.  If you had an old action handler contribution you would get a message as you describe.

Check what is in your extensions (plugin.xml).

Comment: running juno as is mentioned in the question :) Will look through your other suggestions.

Comment: I was looking for a specific version (M20130130 for example).  Also, Juno Service Release 1 is out, and Juno Service Release 2 will be out shortly.

Comment: Ok - sorry. It is 20120614. This problem is still persistent. All behaviour is as expected (action shows up etc..) but error message is still there.

Answer (score 0):

A folder called runtime-EclipseApplication is created when you run. You could try deleting it.