# My ADT Bundle says "could not find SDK folder"

Tags: android

I am installing my ADT bundle for Android and it keeps giving me this error that says, could not find SDK folder, what do I do to make it work again?

I'm having multiple errors as well as that like:

```
"Unable to find Action Set: org.eclipse.wb.core.ui.actionset"
"Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui/icons/eview16/task-list.gif"."
"Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui/icons/eview16/task-list.gif"."
```

And many more.

Comment: Have you installed SDK?

Answer (score 7):

Did you renamed the unzipped directory? If yes, don't do this. Or it may happen if you changed the location of unzipped directory.

Solution (If you don't want to unzip ADT bundle again)

In Eclipse:- goto `Window->Preferences->Android` and you will see "`SDK Location`".
Browse to your SDK location and say `OK`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I didn't rename the unzipped directory, I'm not even sure what that is in the first place.

Comment: do you have adt bundle which you downloded? If yes unzip that at your required location... after unzip do not move the location of unzipped folder

Comment: alright I didn't do that but it still gives me the error. Also, I deleted everything that I had from my last time I used the package so I right now have nothing. It is also giving me multiple other errors.

Comment: This is the eclipse plugins error. Better is to unzip the ADT bundle again and use fresh copy :)

Comment: Then try my last given steps

Comment: It's not letting me choose any folder because it says it can't find the tools in the folder so it's not letting me press OK.

Comment: :D try this commad `chmod a+x android` with root permission.  Before doing this create new workspace and try to open eclipse

Comment: Where do I type that? Also, what is chmod? Can you please be more descriptive I'm sorry for the burden.

Comment: on terminal this command should be run. before doing this you can check with creating the new workspace

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535784/eclipse-missing-action-set this also might help you

Answer (score 4):

on Eclipse Go to  `Windows > Preferences > Android` you will see place for `SDK location` [image: see this image]. As you can see in my image browse directory **android-sdk**.

**Note-** This location will be different for you depending where you installed the sdk.

Comment: So should I add all of this to my ADT?

Comment: It's not letting me choose any folder because it says it can't find the tools in the folder so it's not letting me press OK.

Comment: Have you sorted out everything?

Comment: Yes I have, thanks for all the help. It looks like I just had to change my workspace to reset everything.

Comment: @Crenox if your problem is solved then mark the tick mark on correct answer so that questioned is marked as solved.