# Eclipse: Do I need to uninstall my current version of the ADT plugin to use an older one?

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, sdk, adt

I wish to use an older version of the `ADT plugin` for `Eclipse`, which I found a download link for [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710107/where-can-i-find-older-versions-of-eclipse-adt).

How can I install this within Eclipse, and do I need to uninstall the ADT Plugin that I currently have?

Also, Do I need to use a specific `SDK` to work with this older ADT version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Create your download url: http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-##.#.#.zip. Google uses the version number for the downloads, so if you need 10.0.1, your download would be http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-10.0.1.zip.

2 - Uninstall the current ADT version in Eclipse.

3 - Install the new version as an archive!

Comment: Thanks, how do I uninstall the current adt version?, and also how do I install the new one as an archive?

Comment: You`re welcome. Please follow this link, it will give you some guidance

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097163/uninstalling-android-adt

Check "Troubleshooting ADT Installation"

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but do you know where I can find a list of SDK and ADT compatabilities? I.e. what one works with what

Comment: No need to be sorry, just upvote the answer haha. Kidding bro.
Here's what you need: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html (Revisions)

Comment: Thanksm, is it possible to have two versions of the adt plugin? I.e. one that will work with Android 4.4.2 sdk and one that will work with an older sdk?

Comment: Since eclipse adt is an executable from a folder, an alternative would be downloading two different eclipse ADT bundles, then you can support both.

Comment: Thank you I will do so, I have downloaded the SDK and installed the ADT Plugin for Eclipse Luna, I can see the icons in the toolbar, but when I click on the sdk manager I get the error "Could not find SDK folder", do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: See if it's similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607810/my-adt-bundle-says-could-not-find-sdk-folder