# STS Upgrate leads to MatchLocator problems

Tags: eclipse, spring, scala, maven, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I recently let STS update itself from 3.1 to 3.5 and now I'm getting errors regarding the MatchLocator class.  I'm not sure what MatchLocator is, but it appears to be a core Eclipse service.

When I open STS I get `'Initializing Java Tooling' has encountered a problem.`

> An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Java Tooling".
>   org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/search/matching/MatchLocator

After it's open I get an error marker for each applicationContext.xml in each project that says

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/search/matching/MatchLocator

No lines are marked, just that it's a "Spring Beans Problem"

When I close STS I get `Problmes occurred while trying to save the state of the workbench` with details:

> An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Java Tooling".
>   org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/search/matching/MatchLocator

I've tried downloading a fresh copy of STS 3.5 to a separate directory and each of my workspaces still have this error so I suspect the problem is in the `.metadata` directory.  A couple other Stack Overflow posts have recommended deleting the workspace `.metadata` or `.metadata\.plugins` directories and letting Eclipse rebuild them for that workspace but that didn't fix it either.

I'm running on a Mac with these plugins: m2e Maven Integration and associated plugins, Scala IDE, STS and StartExplorer.

Is there a way to restore the missing MatchLocator files?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue as well with similar plugins on a Mac (without StartExplorer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed this by removing this file in each workspace:

```
[workspace]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi
```

Opening STS from the command line (on mac: `./STS.app/Contents/MacOS/STS -clean`) and viewing stack traces on startup led me to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13884461/1637003

Now all the random ways this bug was manifesting itself have gone away: JUnit tests not running, cmd+clicking to open declarations not working, various MatchLocator errors on startup and shut down.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest solution for this problem is that we have to **launch a new eclipse IDE** and again we install STS tool plugin then import your project.
It works well and u get free from errors.